# SQL Server : get start time and end time with in the multiple night shift

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the Start and End time of this list? I can add date to this time and can get by min and max but you can see `row 3` have next day shift but it will come under same date because it is night shift

I have added normal day shift employee also get the logic right

```
EmployeeId  ShiftDate   ShiftStartTime  ShiftEndTime
-----------------------------------------------------
20040       2017-11-01  21:00:00        23:00:00
20040       2017-11-01  23:00:00        00:30:00
20040       2017-11-01  00:30:00        06:00:00
20124       2017-11-01  09:00:00        16:30:00
20124       2017-11-01  16:30:00        22:00:00
20124       2017-11-01  22:00:00        22:30:00
```

I need it like below:

```
EmployeeId  ShiftDate   ShiftStartTime  ShiftEndTime
----------------------------------------------------
20040       2017-11-01  21:00:00        06:00:00
20124       2017-11-01  09:00:00        22:30:00
```

Comment: That's some maddening data right there. What happens if they work a split shift. Like if they come in and work some hours in the morning, leave and come back and work some hours at night that span until the next day? Are the hours always connected like this to other records on the same `shiftdate`?

Comment: Please indicate the 'actual date' that the shifts start on... Don't add the employee to filter the list - please add the full list to your question

Comment: @Grantly I'm not following (I'm also not OP so maybe this makes sense and I'm just not getting it). What would you consider the `Actual date` here. What if that data isn't available? What does "Don't add the employee to filter the list" mean. What does "The full list to your question" mean?

Comment: @JNevill  Actaul date is say for Morning Shift, starting at 11:30 at night, until like 8:30 am the next day... The Morning Shift might easily be considered to be 'RUN' on the following day (when the Shift ENDS).  So all administrative reporting / paycheck etc will be based on the Actual date.  A shift can only have ONE date, so there are always business rules (good or bad) that dictate this.  Linking an employee to the list doesn't necessarily make the list any more relevant or complete or helpful...It just adds another potential error... The full list of data (if not too huge) is much better

Comment: @JNevill If you take my Morning shift example above, then notice the complexity when you tell your Employee to come to work on 1/1/2000 at 11:30pm....  But the SHIFT he works (written on his pay check) is the Morning Shift on the 2/1/2000 (UK dates).  So the business must be very clear about actual and 'reporting' Shift dates - otherwise the employees could be called a day late

Comment: @JNevill each employee works in different roles in employee 20040 works in 3 roles end of the day we sum the total hours and record it in shift date

Comment: @Grantlyshift starts in  2017-11-01  21:00:00 and finish at next day 2017-11-02 06:00:00 but the problem is we don't have date to add and all 3 shifts belongs to 2017-11-01

Comment: @JNevill yes always connected to same date like this some time they work in 2 roles or may be in 4 roles as well but all comes under starting shift date

Comment: In that case you really need an EmployeeShift (or EmployeeShiftDate) table, to store which actual Shifts an employee worked

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding your Question.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Do you want to calculate the 'HOURS' worked in each Shift?  If so, please Edit your question

Comment: no no is not to calculate the hours question is clear and @JNevill got the point

Answer (score 0):

In a commercial environment we solved this by attaching a FLAG to each shift.  The Flag would indicate the 'Reporting Date' of the Shift...The Flag would have have a value of 1 if the 'Reporting / Administrative date' was the 'next' day.  0 for the same day.  -1 for the previous day (which we never used...depends on your scenario)

I modified your table to show a possible SHIFTS table, which should also have a NAME column I guess (like Morning, Afternoon, Day, Night shift etc)

```
ReportFlag ShiftStartTime  ShiftEndTime
1         21:00:00        23:00:00
1         23:00:00        00:30:00
0         00:30:00        06:00:00
0         09:00:00        16:30:00
0         16:30:00        22:00:00
1         22:00:00        22:30:00
```

Notice how I added 1 - to say that 'this shift' is actually considered to be on the 'next' day.

Then you can use your flag value 0,1 to add to DATE functions in your queries too

Comment: here reporting date is clear reporting date is 2017-11-01

Comment: And then when is your 'actual' date.  They cannot always be the same (with real life Shifts)

Comment: You can use my technique to find the **actual** date from the **reporting date** or the other way around.  Its quite dynamic

Comment: problem is shift start and end time columns not have dates all shifts need to be in same date

Comment: if is according to you i can get by min max that is not the case

Comment: What are the business rules for Shifts?  If this is a real life problem - it actually gets quite complicated.  Please add more relevant info to your Question :)

Comment: business role is clear employee can work in multiple roles like above and need to sum the hours and add it to shift date

Comment: it is a real life problem and it is used in actual system but we are trying to generate a report and got stuck